# Batch, using Start Cmd to run cmd in new window

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I want to open a new cmd prompt from my batch script and set that as the "active window" to run the following cmds in my script.

I know how to open the new cmd promt:

```
start cmd \k "cd c:/users"
```

Now whenever I enter in cmds to perform under that line it executes in the prompt that I used to call my batch script. How can I set it so they all execute in the new window, there will be a lot of cmds executed and i have tried the && and & but it doesn't work.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
@echo off
start cmd /k "cd c:\users" ^&set/p check=Did it work? ^& call echo %%check%%
```

*note: c:\ not c:/*

Or:

```
@echo off
start cmd /k "cd /d c:\users" ^&^
set/p check=Did it work? ^&^
call echo %%check%%
```